# How to add a user to GitHub and generate token?

Tags: github

I have a service that is running (on customer premise) which needs to clone a github repo. I don't want to use my credentials/token to be used.  How can I solve this? Can I have another user (read only) added to the project? If so can I do it without an email address? Or can I generate a read-only token?

Is there any other solution for this problem?